# Convert SQL Statement to Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to convert the following into Rails Ruby code:

```
SELECT * FROM ALBUMS
WHERE TITLE='Greatest Hits'
AND ARTIST='The Beatles';

SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM ALBUMS
WHERE TITLE='Greatest Hits'
AND ARTIST='The Beatles';
```

For the first, I've read about the pluck method in Ruby, but I don't know how to pluck given multiple limitations, in this case, not just title, but also artist.

For the second, I want to just count how many occurrences of title and artist being the same.

Please help? 
My best source: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM ALBUMS
WHERE TITLE='Greatest Hits'
AND ARTIST='The Beatles';
```

Assuming a model named Album

```
Album.where(title: "Greatest Hits", artist: "The Beatles")
```

For the second

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM ALBUMS
WHERE TITLE='Greatest Hits'
AND ARTIST='The Beatles';
```

Use the `count` method.

```
Album.where(title: "Greatest Hits", artist: "The Beatles").count(:id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here is the link to my follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113578/using-plucked-values-in-ruby-on-rails